# When plotting datetime index data, put markers in the plot on specific days (e.g. weekend)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I create a pandas dataframe with a DatetimeIndex like so:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create datetime index and random data column
todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
index = pd.date_range(todays_date-datetime.timedelta(10), periods=14, freq='D')
data = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=14)
columns = ['A']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

# initialize new weekend column, then set all values to 'yes' where the index corresponds to a weekend day
df['weekend'] = 'no'
df.loc[(df.index.weekday == 5) | (df.index.weekday == 6), 'weekend'] = 'yes'

print(df)
```

Which gives

```
            A weekend
2014-10-13  7      no
2014-10-14  6      no
2014-10-15  7      no
2014-10-16  9      no
2014-10-17  4      no
2014-10-18  6     yes
2014-10-19  4     yes
2014-10-20  7      no
2014-10-21  8      no
2014-10-22  8      no
2014-10-23  1      no
2014-10-24  4      no
2014-10-25  3     yes
2014-10-26  8     yes
```

I can easily plot the `A` colum with pandas by doing:

```
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

which plots a line of the `A` column but leaves out the `weekend` column as it does not hold numerical data.

[image: Plot of 'A' but not of 'weekend']

How can I put a "marker" on each spot of the `A` column where the `weekend` column has the value `yes`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meanwhile I found out, it is as simple as using boolean indexing in pandas. Doing the plot directly with pyplot instead of pandas' own plot wrapper (which is more convenient to me):

```
plt.plot(df.index, df.A)
plt.plot(df[df.weekend=='yes'].index, df[df.weekend=='yes'].A, 'ro')
```

[image: Plot of 'A' with weekend markers]

Now, the red dots mark all weekend days which are given by `df.weekend='yes'` values.

Comment: You could shorten it a smidge with `df['A'][df['weekend'] == 'yes'].plot(style='ro')` which is a bit more readable (IMO) but still, nice self-answer.